# How can I plot a boxplot with some of the coulmns of a dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have the following dataset:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA5nF.png)

Out of the thirteen columns present here, I want to construct a box plot with four of the columns namely: 'age', 'income', 'share' and 'expenditure'.

I want to follow the format:

```
#Median age of the applicants
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
sns.boxplot(y='age',data=credit9,palette='BuPu')
```

Can anybody please tell how may I do that.

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @brentertainer Actually I want to plot data for some of the columns. And I want the colour palette to be included. And I want the four boxplots in a single figure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal reproducible example of what you seem to want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(size=(100, 3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

subset = ['a', 'b']

sns.boxplot(data=df[subset], palette='BuPu')
plt.show()
```